# What do these python `import` statements mean?

Tags: python

At the beginning of a python script, there are some `import` statements. Could someone explain what they imply?

```
import getopt  
import os  
import re   
import string  
import sys  
import getpass  
import urllib  
import subprocess
```

Comment: Surely, with this title, ANY operating system tag would be more useful than `python`?

Comment: I'm wondering why this question got downvotes. Granted, the OP could have done a little bit of Googling first, but is this not a valid question?

Comment: The question is valid, but is a bad question, thus the downvote. You don't downvote only invalid questions. In fact, invalid questions should be closed instead of downvoted.

Comment: @nosklo: What's bad about it?

Comment: downvote for showing zero motivation for doing basic research alone

Comment: You don't have to post "I looked through 100 pages of Google". Maybe he just doesn't know where to look or what the other sources mean?

Comment: @mathepic: 100 pages is nonsense. google("python import"); 2nd hit is docs; 3rd hit is tutorial

Comment: @intuited: The OP appears based on his answers and other questions to be a non-newbie Java programmer. Java has a moderately similar `import` statement. What reaction would you expect if you asked what does a Java import statement like `import javax.swing.JOptionPane;` mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `import` statements are similar (but different) to the `#include` statements in C: they allow you to use functions defined elsewhere (either in a standard module, or your own).

For example, module `sys` allows you to do this:

```
import sys
# ... somewhere down in the file
sys.exit(0)
```

Which would terminate your program. Note that **you** did not have to write any code for the `exit()` function, but it is defined within the standard `sys` module that ships with the interpreter.

Any Python tutorial should explain this. For example, [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's importing modules (like libraries).
When imported in this manner you'll find in the code calls to functions of this kind < module_name >.< function >

To know what each module do and offers, look at the documentation; a quick googling "python " should land you in the right place.